# Sitecore campaign triggered doesn't show results in the report

Tags: sitecore-client, xdb, experience-analytics

I'm trying to trigger a campaign via API. There are no issues in the logs, the code runs with no issues, but I don't see any results in the respective campaign report, it always says "`No Data Found`". Any suggestions

```
ICampaignActivityDefination cd= new this.FindCampaignById(new ID(id));
PageEventData ped= Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.TriggerCampaign(cd);
```

We get the `pageeventdata` confirmation as "`Triggered the campaign id`".

Comment: Try rebuilding indexes if you don't see anything in logs.

Comment: @VikrantPunwatkar which index specifically, I do not see any index related to analytics.

Comment: Still its "No Data Found" despite running all indexes several times.